# Odd animation with .matchedGeometryEffect and NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, geometryreader

I'm working on creating a view which uses `matchedGeometryEffect`, embedded within a `NavigationView`, and when presenting the second view another `NavigationView`.

The animation "works" and it matches correctly, however when it toggles from view to view it happens to *swing* as if unwinding from the navigation stack.

However, if I comment out the `NavigationView` on the secondary view the matched geometry works correctly.

I am working on iOS 14.0 and above.

### Sample code

#### Model / Mock Data

```swift
struct Model: Identifiable {
  let id = UUID().uuidString
  let icon: String
  let title: String
  let account: String
  let colour: Color
}

let mockItems: [Model] = [
  Model(title: "Test title 1", colour: .gray),
  Model(title: "Test title 2", colour: .blue),
  Model(title: "Test title 3", colour: .purple)
  ...
]
```

#### Card View

```swift
struct CardView: View {
  let item: Model
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(item.title)
        .font(.title3)
        .fontWeight(.heavy)
    }
    .padding()
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, alignment: .leading)
    .background(item.colour)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
  }
}
```

#### Secondary / Detail View

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
  @Binding var isShowingDetail: Bool
  let item: Model
  let animation: Namespace.ID
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {  // <--- comment out here and it works
      VStack {
        CardView(item: item)
          .matchedGeometryEffect(id: item.id, in: animation)
          .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation { isShowingDetail = false }
          }
          ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor...")
          }
      }
      .padding(.horizontal)
      .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
  }
}
```

#### Primary View

```swift
struct ListView: View {
  @State private var selectedCard: Model?
  @State private var isShowingCard: Bool = false
  @Namespace var animation
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      NavigationView {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
          ForEach(mockItems) { item in
            CardView(item: item)
              .matchedGeometryEffect(id: item.id, in: animation)
              .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                  selectedCard = item
                  isShowingCard = true
                }
              }
          }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Test title")
      }
      .padding(.horizontal)
      .navigationViewStyle(.stack)

      // show detail view
      if let selectedCard = selectedCard, isShowingCard {
        DetailView(
          isShowingDetail: $isShowingCard,
          item: selectedCard,
          animation: animation
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Video examples

#### With `NavigationView` in DetailView

[image]

#### Without `NavigationView` in DetailView

*Ignore the list view still visible*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need second `NavigationView` (actually I don't see links at all, so necessity of the first one is also under question). Anyway we can just change the layout order and put everything into one `NavigationView`, like below.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

```
struct ListView: View {
  @State private var selectedCard: Model?
  @State private var isShowingCard: Bool = false
  @Namespace var animation
  var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
        ZStack {         // container !!
          if let selectedCard = selectedCard, isShowingCard {
            DetailView(
              isShowingDetail: $isShowingCard,
              item: selectedCard,
              animation: animation
            )
          } else {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
              ForEach(mockItems) { item in
                CardView(item: item)
                  .matchedGeometryEffect(id: item.id, in: animation)
                  .onTapGesture {
                      selectedCard = item
                      isShowingCard = true
                  }
              }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test title")
          }
      }
      .padding(.horizontal)
      .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
      .animation(.default, value: isShowingCard)   // << animated here !!
    }
  }
}

struct DetailView: View {
  @Binding var isShowingDetail: Bool
  let item: Model
  let animation: Namespace.ID
  var body: some View {
      VStack {
        CardView(item: item)
          .matchedGeometryEffect(id: item.id, in: animation)
          .onTapGesture {
                isShowingDetail = false
          }
          ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor...")
          }
      }
      .padding(.horizontal)
      .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
      .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
  }
}
```

[Test module is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestMatchInNavigationView.swift)

Comment: thank you! i think i got confused to add in a second navigation view!